# validate array or an array of integers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a input request that can be an integer or an array of integer values.

How can I check validation of that in Laravel? I'm using Laravel 5.5.I know that there is a simple `array` validation rules that checks an input is an array or not:

> array
>
> The field under validation must be a PHP array.

Is there any predefined validation rule or should I write a new one? if yes, How?

Comment: you can create same custom validation rules, which will check if you input field is and `array` or just un `integer`

Comment: each array elements should be an integer . how to check it ?

Comment: [Laravel Valadating arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = $request->all();

//Check if input param is an array
if(is_array($input['item']))
{
  //Array validator
  $Validator = Validator::make($input, 
    [
        'item' => 'required', //Array with key 'item' must exist
        'item.*' => 'sometimes|integer', //All values should be integers
    ]);
}
else
{
  //Integer validator
  $Validator = Validator::make($input, 
    [
        'item'   => 'required|integer',
    ]);
}
```

Use **sometimes** it applies validation rule only if that input parameter exist. Hope this helps

Comment: How can I write it as a custom validation rule for next uses

Comment: Its up to you. You can use either ways. Above solution will work for you I think. It will save your time and efforts :)

Comment: @A.B.Developer did you find this helpful ?